# When I introduced pod install in console, the error (NoMethodError - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Pod::Specification name="Parse">) appears

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, backend

I'm trying to install the pod in the folder of my project, but this erros continue appearing.

NoMethodError - undefined method `to_ary' for #

I can't run my iOS app to try the connection between parse and my app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Experiencing the exact same problem and couldn't find anything else related to this issue. Does anybody have come up on this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears in particular when using ruby-2.3.0 version, check the following [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4345) for more information on that. Please follow the instructions below to fix the error message that you get when performing a `pod install` or `pod update`:

1. Uninstall CocoaPods

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
```

2. Install ruby-2.2.1:

```
rvm install 2.2.1
```

3. Set the ruby-2.2.1 version previously installed as the default ruby version to use and uninstall the ruby-2.3.0 version :

```
rvm list
rvm --default use 2.2.1
rvm uninstall ruby-2.3.0
rvm list
rvm use
```

4. Install CocoaPods

```
gem install cocoapods
```

At that point everything should normally work like a charm.